# How to solve given recurrence relation?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

From the following recurrence relation:

$a_n =- a_{n-1}+8a_{n-2}+12a_{n-3}+25\cdot3^{n-2}-18n^2+48n+14$,  for $n\geq3$

Where $a_0=6, a_1 = 0 $ and $a_2=57$.

---

My attempt:

I have generated a sequence but I have found that the result is simply too large to put into a form that can be decomposed into partial fractions.

My result is as follows:

[image]

Any help or hints on how I can go about this are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to do it by generating functions? It is easy to solve directly.

Comment: Really? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence relation seems to have disappeared from the question, so I repeat it here: $a_n=-a_{n-1}+8a_{n-2}+12a_{n-3}+25\cdot3^{n-2}-18n^2+48n+14$, with $a_0=6,a_1=0,a_2=57$.

Ignoring the last four terms, we have a standard linear recurrence relation. The associated polynomial has roots 3,-2, so its general solution is $A3^n+B(-2)^n+Cn(-2)^n$.

Next we need to find a particular solution. For the $25\cdot3^{n-2}$ we expect $Dn3^n$ to work for some $D$ (since $3^n$ is part of the general solution). For the $-18n^2+48n-14$ we expect $En^2+Fn+G$ to work. We duly find $n3^n+n^2+3n$.

So finally we have to get $A,B,C$ from the given values for $a_0,a_1,a_2$, giving $A=1,B=5,C=0$, hence $a_n=3^n+5(-2)^n+n 3^n+n^2+3n$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much. I'll read it over and learn it.

Comment: Sorry to disturb again. But I am not sure how you obtained
the n3^n + n^2 + 3n

I am struggling to work it out.

Comment: In general if $f(n)$ appears the first thing to try is $a_n=f(n)$. In this case $-18n^2$ appears, one tries putting $a_n=n^2$ and sees what that gives. Usually it gives a multiple of what one wants, so one then adjusts. Here that was not necessary. Where $f(n)$ is part of the general solution that will not work (as with $3^n$), so one tries $nf(n)$.